# VSCode Extension Development: Rejected Promise Error When Running "sonarqube-scanner-npm"

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, vscode-extensions, stack-trace

Developing a VSCode extension and trying to use [sonarqube-scanner-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sonarqube-scanner) package. When run the script below explicitly on a terminal with the following command  `node sonarqube-scanner-script.ts`, it works as expected.

```
const scanner = require("sonarqube-scanner");
scanner(
    {
        serverUrl: "https://sonarcloud.io",
        token: "my_api_key",
        options: {
          "sonar.projectName": "My project name",
          "sonar.projectDescription": "",
          "sonar.organisation": "My org",
          "sonar.sources": "src",
          "sonar.tests": "test",
        },
    },
    () => process.exit()
);
```

However, when put the code inside the extension it causes an error.

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  //...
  let sonarqubeTest = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "myextension.sonarqubeTest",
    () => {
      // The code placed here will be executed every time the command is executed
      scanner(
        {
          serverUrl: "https://sonarcloud.io",
          token: "my_api_key",
          options: {
            "sonar.projectName": "My project name",
            "sonar.projectDescription": "",
            "sonar.organisation": "My org",
            "sonar.sources": "src",
            "sonar.tests": "test",
          },
        },
        () => process.exit()
      );
    }
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(sonarqubeTest);
  //...
}
```

This is the error encountered:

```
rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: Command failed: /Users/[me]/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006-macosx/bin/sonar-scanner --from=ScannerNpm/3.3.0
extensionHostProcess.js:144
stack trace: Error: Command failed: /Users/[me]/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006-macosx/bin/sonar-scanner --from=ScannerNpm/3.3.0
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:934:11)
    at execFileSync (node:child_process:970:15)
    at func (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:2131)
    at scan (/Users/[me]/[...]/node_modules/sonarqube-scanner/src/index.js:40:3)
```